# Intermittent 500 error from PayPal button submission with JavaScript

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, drupal-8

I'm testing a basic PayPal button form created dynamically with PHP, and submitted with JS to the sandbox after a short delay when a page loads. About half the time it works fine, and about half the time PayPal responds with a 500 error. When I get the error, I can go back in the browser and let it resubmit the exact same form, at which point, again, it sometimes works and sometimes gets the error.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Could this be some sort of cookies issue? I've submitted a ticket to PayPal -- no response yet. Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the relevant code. It's a Drupal 8 site, and this is in a custom module using the Form API for a multi-step form. `buildForm()` is called (then `validateForm()`) then `submitForm()`. The flow in this case starts after 'step' 3 is built. The customer clicks 'pay', and `submitForm()` is called.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    ...
    //'step' 3
    ...
    //'step' 4 is just to redirect to PayPal
    elseif ($form_state->get('step') == 4) {
        //prints in main form content area
        $form['redirecting'] = array(
            '#type' => 'html_tag',
            '#tag' => 'div',
            '#value' => $this->t('Redirecting to PayPal...'),
        );
    }
    ...
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    ...
    //called after 'step' 3
    //gets id of record just inserted into database
    $paypal_invoice = $query->execute()->fetchField();
    $paypal_item_name = '[name of item]';
    $paypal_amount = $form_state->getValue('amount');
    $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

    $paypal_html =
        '<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="paypal_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="______________">
            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
            <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="' . $paypal_invoice . '">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="' . $paypal_item_name . '">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' . $paypal_amount . '">
            <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
            <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://__________________">
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://______________?cancel=1&token=' . $token . '">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById("paypal_form").submit();
            }, 4000);
        </script>';

    //make sure html tags are evaluated
    $rendered_message = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create($paypal_html);
    //string will be added to message area of form when 'step' 4 is loaded with buildForm()
    drupal_set_message($rendered_message);

    $form_state->set(['step'], 4);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case it helps someone else: this is a PayPal sandbox issue.

I generated an equivalent button form on the PayPal website, submitted it to the sandbox numerous times outside of my code, and got similar intermittent 500 errors.

Then I switched the references in my code to the live PayPal info, ran it numerous times (without completing the transactions), and got no errors.

So there's something about the sandbox configuration which is different than the live configuration and causes this (maybe memory issue?). This must not be a unique situation, so it's frustrating PayPal doesn't document limitations with the sandbox. But glad it appears to be ok to go ahead.

EDIT: Here's PayPal's response confirming.

> We are aware of some issues with our PayPal Sandbox that intermittently causes a valid request to fail with a 500 Internal Server Error. Our developers are working on this issue and I will update you when the issue has been fully resolved.
>
> Please note that this issue is only affecting the sandbox environment. No impact has been noted on the production environment.

FURTHER EDIT: Update from PayPal.

> Thank you for your patience as we tracked down the source of the instability on our Sandbox environment.
>
> The PayPal engineers have resolved the issue that was resulting in the frequent Internal Server Errors. However, they have indicated that all requests should be going to the https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ domain. If your integration is sending to https://sandbox.paypal.com (no www), then you may still experience some latency. Please update your integration, if this is the case for you, to include the www.